# Is there a web stack optimized to minimize server-side coding?

Tags: javascript, security, rest, client-side, user-roles

For a couple recent projects on our corporate intranet, I have used a very simple stack of nginx + redis + [webdis](http://webd.is/) + client-side javascript to implement some simple data analysis tools.  The experience was **absolutely wonderful**, especially compared to my previous experience with other stacks (including custom c++, apache/mod_perl, ASP.Net MVC, .Net HttpListener, Ruby on Rails, and a bit of Node.js).  Given the availability of client-side templating tools and frontend libraries such as jquery-ui, it seems that I could happily implement much more complicated web-apps using such a no-server-side-code stack (perhaps substituting/augmenting redis with couchdb if warranted)...

The major limitation of this stack, of course, is that my database is directly exposed to the network - acceptable in this case on a firewalled corporate network, but not really an option if I wanted to use the same techniques on the internet.  I need to have some level of server-side logic to securely handle authentication and user-role management.

Are there any best practices or common development stacks for this?  Ideally I'd like something that is lightweight, and gives me a simple framework for filtering the client-side requests through my custom user-role logic before forwarding them on to the database back-end.  I'm not interested in any sort of server-side templating, or ActiveRecord-style storage-level abstractions.

Answer (score 2):

I can't comment on a framework.

You've already mentioned the primary weakness of this, especially on the internet, that being security. The problem there is not just authentication. The problem there is essentially the openness of the client, in this case the web browser, and the protocol, notably HTTP using JSON or XML or some other plaintext protocol.

Consider one example. It's quite simple. Imagine an HTTP service that takes an SQL query and returns a collection of JSON representing the rows. This is straightforward to write. You could probably pound out a nascent one in less than an hour from scratch using any tool that gives you SQL access to an RDBMS.

Arguably, back in the Golden Days of Client Server development, this is exactly what folks did, only instead of a some data tunneled over HTTP, folks used a DB specific driver and sent SQL text over to the back in DB directly.

The problem today is that the protocols are too open. If you implemented that SQL service mentioned above, you essentially turn your entire application in a SQL injection vector.

You simply can not secure something like that in the wild. The protocol is open to trivial observation (every browser comes with a built in packet sniffer, effectively today), along with all of the source code for the application. If you try to encrypt the data, that's all done on the client as well -- with the source to the process, as well as any keys involved.

CouchDB, for example, can not be secured this way. If someone has rights to the server, they have rights to all of the data. ALL of the data. The stuff you want them to see, and the stuff you don't.

The solution, naturally, is a service layer. Something that speaks at a higher level than simply raw data streams. Something that can be secured, and can keep secrets from the clients. But that, naturally, takes server side programming to enable, and its a ostensibly more work, more layers, more data conversion, more a pain.

Back in the day, folks would write entire systems using nothing but stored procedures in the DB. The procedures would have rights that the users invoking them did not, thus you could limit at the server what a user could or could not see or change. You could given them unlimited SELECT capability on a restricted view, perhaps, while a stored procedure would have rights to actually change data or access some of the hidden columns.

Stored procedures have mostly been replaced by application layers and application servers, with the DB being more and more relegated to "dumb storage". But the concepts are similar.

There's value for some scenarios to publishing data straight to the web, like you analytics example. That's a specific, read heavy niche. But beyond that, the concept doesn't work well, I fear. Obfuscated JS is hard to read, but not secure.

This is likely why you may have a little difficulty locating such a framework (I haven't looked at all, myself).